# Help understand a step in a proof regarding Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In my textbook Riemann-Stieltjes integral is defined as the following. If you are familiar with this definition, you can scroll down right to my question.

> [image]

My problem is with the following proof. The proof is to show $f,\phi$ has no common discontinuity (boxed blue). **I don't get the part underlined red**. **Why such choice of $\xi_{i_0},\xi_{i_0-1}$ is valid**? For example, if $f$ is a constant function on $[a,b]$ except for that $\overline x$ is a removable discontinuity of $f$, then it looks to me that we cannot have such choice that $|f(\xi_{i_0})-f(\xi_{i_0-1})|>\mu$ for some $\mu>0$.

Thank you!

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

That is the negation of the definition of continuity. If $f$ is continuous at $a$ then $$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta >0 s.t \mid \xi_1 -a\mid<\delta \Rightarrow \mid f(\xi_1)-f(a)\mid<\epsilon $$ 
Now if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$ we will have $$\exists \epsilon \forall \delta\mid \xi_1 -a\mid<\delta  \&\mid f(\xi_1)-f(a)\mid\geq\epsilon $$ by using this proposition towtimes you can reach the desired answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know this negation, but I still don't understand. Can you help check the counterexample I give in my question, i.e. $f$ being a constant function except for having removable discontinuity at $x=\overline x$?

Comment: Dear Tony in discontinuity case we cannot take the values of function so close to each other, that is if $f$ is discontinuous at $\bar{x}$ then it is imposible to make $\mid f(x)-f(\bar{x}) \mid <\epsilon$ so it must be $\geq \epsilon.$